# How do I get the subscription status of a user in PayPal subscription API

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to get whether the subscription is cancelled or not by the user in a certain period of time and if the subscription is cancelled I will block user from using some of the features how do I get the current status of the subscription in JavaScript without Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to read the documentation about that Paypal API that developer.payplay provides https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get. You just need to call

```
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "status_update_time": "2019-04-09T10:27:27Z"
```

and make manually the comparassion getting the status value.